# React-Admin: implementing dependant filters

Tags: react-admin

I'm working on a react-admin page where I want to display some filters depending on the values of another one. To do so, I'm using the `filterValues` from the `ListContext` and simply show/hide the dependant filters:

```
const PostFilter = (props) => {
  const { filterValues } = useListContext();
  const { mainType } = filterValues;

  return (
    <Filter {...props}>
      <SelectInput
        source="mainType"
        alwaysOn
        choices={[
          { id: "type_1", name: "Type 1" },
          { id: "type_2", name: "Type 2" },
          { id: "type_3", name: "Type 3" }
        ]}
      />
      {mainType === "type_1" && (
        <SelectInput
          source="type1"
          alwaysOn
          choices={[
            { id: "type_1_a", name: "A" },
            { id: "type_1_b", name: "B" },
            { id: "type_1_c", name: "C" }
          ]}
        />
      )}
      {mainType === "type_2" && (
        <SelectInput
          source="type2"
          alwaysOn
          choices={[
            { id: "type_2_a", name: "A" },
            { id: "type_2_b", name: "B" },
            { id: "type_2_c", name: "C" }
          ]}
        />
      )}
    </Filter>
  );
};
```

This visually works fine but if I choose a value in one of the child filter and then change the main filter, the url is still containing the filter value even though it's not on screen anymore. As the url contains a wrong filter, then the list is not filtered properly.

To workaround this, I played with a `useEffect` and the `setFilters` function but it feels super hacky:

```
const { filterValues, displayedFilters, setFilters } = useListContext();
  const { mainType } = filterValues;

  // we need this workaround because these 3 values are not stable
  // and get be used as the effect dependencies. However, we still want to be sure
  // to always reference their latest version
  const refs = React.useRef({ filterValues, displayedFilters, setFilters });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    refs.current = { filterValues, displayedFilters, setFilters };
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const filters = { ...refs.current.filterValues };
    if (mainType !== "type_1") {
      delete filters.type1;
    }
    if (mainType !== "type_2") {
      delete filters.type_2;
    }
    refs.current.setFilters(filters, refs.current.displayedFilters);
  }, [mainType]);
```

Here's a sandbox showing the result: https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-mountain-i62p3?file=/src/posts.js

Is there a better way to achieve what I want?